# Getting -nan(ind) on double addition c++

Tags: c++, double, addition

I am running into a problem when adding two doubles together, the variable startImpatience is a vector of double and the value of each element is initialized to 1.0 in the constructor of the class. 
As soon as the line `startImpatience[id] += ((1.0 - dif) * dt)` is reached the value of the element gets value `-nan(ind)`.
Here is the code snippet:

```
double pref_magnitude = sqrt((cPreferredVelocity[id].x * cPreferredVelocity[id].x) + (cPreferredVelocity[id].y * cPreferredVelocity[id].y));

double magnitude = sqrt((cVelocity[id].x * cVelocity[id].x) + (cVelocity[id].y * cVelocity[id].y));

double dif = pref_magnitude - magnitude / pref_magnitude;

startImpatience[id] *= (1.0 - dt);
// startImpatience[id] has a value

startImpatience[id] += ((1.0 - dif) * dt);
// startImpatience[id] is -nan(ind)
```

Every variable of which you don't see initialization, yes they are all of type double or vector of double.

I cannot see what is wrong with the code, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Debug and double check the actual values of dif and dt at the line in question, and make sure those are valid (e.g. stack corruption issue?)

Comment: Perfect time to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  It will be orders of magnitude faster than trying to debug programs like this through StackOverflow, and knowing how to debug a program is a valuable skill for every C++ programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it is actually kind of an odd situation. We are working with a new framework and running it in Debug configuration stopped working during the development. Two different issues we are working on but also running short of time.
I was honestly hoping for something wrong with doubles and the += operator. 
Thanks again anyways!

Comment: printf debugging works